# How can I set the size of my Tkinter widgets in pixels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Every time I have to design a GUI in Python, my go-to is always PyQt5 (Qt Designer 5) because it's, in my opinion, easier than Tkinter, but now I have an assignment and it's mandatory to use Tkinter.

The GUI I want to implement in Tkinter is this:

GUI in Qt Designer 5

[image]

This is a piece of the code I did for the Tkinter GUI design:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Text
from tkinter import ttk

class MiApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        self.promDaily = []
        self.datos = {}
        self.csv = " "
        self.botonCSV = ttk.Button(main_window,text="Escoger CSV",width=91,command=self.ChooseCSVFile)
        self.botonCSV.place(x=9,y=16)
        self.pathCSV = ttk.Entry(main_window,width=351,state="disable")
        self.pathCSV.place(x=120,y=17)
        self.labelAbsc = ttk.Label(main_window,text="Abscisa:",width=47)
        self.labelAbsc.place(x=9,y=52)
        self.labelOrden = ttk.Label(main_window,text="Ordenada:",width=55)
        self.labelOrden.place(x=120,y=52)
        self.labelPromD = ttk.Label(main_window,text="Promedio diario:",width=79)
        self.labelPromD.place(x=245,y=52)
        self.comboBAbsc = ttk.Combobox(main_window,width=91)
        self.comboBAbsc.place(x=9,y=78)
        self.comboBOrden = ttk.Combobox(main_window, width=91)
        self.comboBOrden.place(x=120, y=78)
        self.botonCalc = ttk.Button(main_window,text="Calcular",width=75)
        self.botonCalc.place(x=245,y=78)
        self.posibilidadCalc = ttk.Entry(main_window,width=211)
        self.posibilidadCalc.place(x=245,y=114)
        self.botonGraph = ttk.Button(main_window,width=75)
        self.botonGraph.place(x=62,y=201)
        self.textMaxMin = Text(main_window,width=211,height=131)
        self.textMaxMin.place(x=245,y=147)
        (...)
root = Tk()
root.config(width=480,height=337)
mainW = ttk.Frame(root,width=480,height=337)
mainW.pack()
root.resizable(0,0)
app = MiApp(mainW)
app.mainloop()
```

Now, my Tkinter GUI looks like this:

GUI in Tkinter

[image]

How can I set those width values as pixels?

I appreciate your attention.

Comment: why do you need to set the width in pixels? What's wrong with using a width in characters? You can pretty easily get the look you want using widths in characters. It would also probably be a lot easier to use `grid` than `place` to save you from having to do a bunch of math.

Comment: I need to set the width in pixels bc that GUI data was taken from Qt Designer's coordinates and dimensions, which are given in pixels, and I need the design to be as sober as possible, so I used Qt Designer as a guide to save me some time, bc I thought Tkinter also used pixels by default (I was so wrong hahaha).

Answer (score 1):

Unbeknownst to me, defining width and height inside place() after creating the Frame allows placing by pixels:

```
    def __init__(self,main_window):
    super().__init__(main_window)
    self.promDaily = []
    self.guidepromDaily = []
    self.datos = {}
    self.csv = " "
    self.minmax = " "
    self.botonCSV = ttk.Button(main_window,text="Escoger CSV",
         command=self.ChooseCSVFile)
    self.botonCSV.place(x=9,y=16,width=91)
    self.pathCSV = ttk.Entry(main_window,state="disable")
    self.pathCSV.place(x=120,y=17,width=351)
    self.labelAbsc = ttk.Label(main_window,text="Abscisa:")
    self.labelAbsc.place(x=9,y=52,width=47)
    self.labelOrden = ttk.Label(main_window,text="Ordenada:")
    self.labelOrden.place(x=120,y=52,width=55)
    self.labelPromD = ttk.Label(main_window,text="Promedio diario:")
    self.labelPromD.place(x=245,y=52,width=95)
    self.comboBAbsc = ttk.Combobox(main_window,state="readonly")
    self.comboBAbsc.place(x=9,y=78,width=91)
    self.comboBOrden = ttk.Combobox(main_window,state="readonly")
    self.comboBOrden.place(x=120, y=78, width=91)
    self.botonCalc = ttk.Button(main_window,text="Calcular", 
        command=self.PromedioDiario)
    self.botonCalc.place(x=245,y=78,width=75)
    self.posibilidadCalc = ttk.Entry(main_window,state="readonly")
    self.posibilidadCalc.place(x=245,y=114,width=211)
    self.botonGraph = ttk.Button(main_window,text="Graficar",
        command=self.GraphCSV)
    self.botonGraph.place(x=62,y=201,width=75)
    self.textMaxMin = Text(main_window,state="disabled")
    self.textMaxMin.place(x=245,y=147, width=211, height=131)
```

Desired GUI Design in Tkinter

[image]

Comment: Each library has default sizes for widget geometry, so the default width of a tkinter button is probably different from that of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend my project https://github.com/cdhigh/tkinter-designer.

tkinter-designer implemented a add-on in VB6, you can design your GUI in VB6 (drag and drop, resize, align, color, key-bind,...), and then this add-on generate a complete code frame. what you will do is add logic code in event method like coding in VB.

PS: You can install nano version of vb6.